# Ruby on rails redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what does it mean ?
  redirect_to "" and return

Comment: See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to

Answer (score 5):

According to the rails API docs: the return portion stops execution of anything else. In other words if you had the below the text would never print because of the return statement.

```
def go_home
    redirect_to(:action => "home") and return
    puts "This will never print"
  end
```

In the next example `and return` is called only `if monkeys.nil?` is true.

```
 def do_something
    redirect_to(:action => "elsewhere") and return if monkeys.nil?
    render :action => "overthere" # won't be called if monkeys is nil
  end
```

from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: Note that this idiom takes advantage of short-circuit evaluation of the boolean `and` expression. If the `redirect_to` returns `false`, Ruby takes the short-circuit and doesn't bother evaluating the remainder of the expression; however, if `redirect_to` returns `true`, then the remainder of the expression must be evaluated. As the remainder is `return`, the effect of the entire expression is: "issue a redirect (302) code and if this really happens, then return without taking any other action".